# CTE having dynamic variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, common-table-expression

I have these 2 example of CTE statement, one is hardcoded and the other is dynamic.  The hardcoded works but not the dynamic.  Can you check what's wrong with my dynamic statement?  Thanks

-- THIS WORKS

```
WITH CTE AS 
( 
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM Citi_v823_21Nov2013.dbo.GroupRelation_Audit
WHERE Citi_v823_21Nov2013.dbo.GroupRelation_Audit.ParentEntityIDCounter =   @ParentEntityIDCounter
AND Citi_v823_21Nov2013.dbo.GroupRelation_Audit.ChildEntityIDCounter =    @ChildEntityIDCounter
AND IsNull(Citi_v823_21Nov2013.dbo.GroupRelation_Audit.AuditDateModified, '1900-01-01') < GETDATE()
ORDER BY GroupRelationCounter DESC
) 
UPDATE CTE SET DateEffectiveTo = @DateEffectiveFrom_GroupRelation
```

--THIS DOESN'T WORK

```
DECLARE @TargetDB NVARCHAR(Max)
DECLARE @SourceDB NVARCHAR(Max)
DECLARE @DateEffectiveFrom_GroupRelation DATETIME
DECLARE @UpdateRecords_GroupRelation NVARCHAR(Max) 
SET @TargetDB = 'Citi_v823_21Nov2013'
SET @SourceDB = 'UATCitiv82320131018'
SET @DateEffectiveFrom_GroupRelation = '2013-09-29'
SET @UpdateRecords_GroupRelation = '
;WITH CTE AS 
( 
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM ' + @TargetDB +  '.dbo.GroupRelation_Audit
WHERE ' + @TargetDB +  '.dbo.GroupRelation_Audit.ParentEntityIDCounter =  ' +   CONVERT(NVARCHAR(Max), @ParentEntityIDCounter) +'
AND ' + @TargetDB +  '.dbo.GroupRelation_Audit.ChildEntityIDCounter = ' +   CONVERT(NVARCHAR(Max), @ChildEntityIDCounter) +'
AND  IsNull(' + @TargetDB +  '.dbo.GroupRelation_Audit.AuditDateModified, ''1900-01-01'') < GETDATE() ''
ORDER BY ' + @TargetDB +  '.dbo.GroupRelation_Audit.GroupRelationCounter DESC
)'
UPDATE CTE SET DateEffectiveTo =  @DateEffectiveFrom_GroupRelation 

EXEC sp_executesql @UpdateRecords_GroupRelation
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your UPDATE statement inside the SQL statement.

The CTE is locally-scoped, so that statement won't known what `CTE` is and will simply throw an invalid object error.

Sample code:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

select *
into ##t
from
(select 3 as b) tmp

select * from ##t;

set @sql = ';WITH a as (select 1 as b) update ##t set b = (select top 1 * from a) '

EXEC sp_executesql @sql

select * from ##t

drop table ##t
```

Comment: What do you get when you try to run it?

Comment: This is the error: Error Message: Must declare the scalar variable "@DateEffectiveFrom_GroupRelation".  I think it something to do with the date

Comment: You have to remove your variable from the UPDATE statement and concatenate it into the @ sql variable's value just like you did with the @ targetDB. That variable isn't known inside the @ sql command you're running.